# getting an error while generating a cookbook using chef generate cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef and learning.I am getting the below error while generating the cook book.i followed the below steps .Please let me know the further steps to proceed.

```
root@ip-IPAddress:/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks# chef generate cookbook webserver
Command 'chef' is available in '/usr/games/chef'
The command could not be located because '/usr/games' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
chef: command not found
```

for that as per the suggestion i added this.

```
root@ip-172-31-7-14:/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks# export PATH="/usr/games:$PATH"
root@ip-172-31-7-14:/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks# chef generate cookbook webserver
Can't open generate: No such file or directory.
Can't open cookbook: No such file or directory.
Can't open webserver: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your operating system is `Ubuntu`, I tried to install `chef` on my ubuntu VPS by following steps, it works well:

1. Download the Chef development kit: https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk/.

   ```
   $ wget https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chefdk/1.3.43/ubuntu/16.04/chefdk_1.3.43-1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install the package, and the PATH will be set automatically,

   ```
   root@Mc:~# dpkg -i chef-server*

   root@Mc:~# chef
   chef         chef-apply   chef-client  chef-shell   chef-solo    chef-vault

   root@Mc:~# chef -v
   Chef Development Kit Version: 1.3.43
   chef-client version: 12.19.36
   delivery version: master (dd319aa632c2f550c92a2172b9d1226478fea997)
   berks version: 5.6.4
   kitchen version: 1.16.0
   ```
3. Generate a cookbook:

   ```
   $ chef generate app first_cookbook
   ```

You can see more details from [chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/quick_start.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't have to install ruby, chefdk comes with embedded ruby.